# Trying to serve png in Node.js: Cannot read property 'end' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a Node, web dev and programming beginner following 'Get Programming with Node.js' by Jonathan Wexler. I've worked up to the end of the section on routing in vanilla Node, with the following code in main.js:

```
  http = require("http"),
  httpStatusCodes = require("http-status-codes"),
  fs = require("fs"); // This is a node js core module which interacts with the filesystem on behalf of the app.
(router = require("./router")),
  (plainTextContentType = {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain",
  }),
  (htmlContentType = {
    "Content-Type": "text/html",
  }),
  (pngContentType = {
    "Content-Type": "image/png",
  }),
  (customReadFile = (file, res) => {
    fs.readFile(`./${file}`, (errors, data) => {
      if (errors) {
        console.log("Error reading the file...");
      }
      res.end(data);
    });
  });

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(httpStatusCodes.OK, plainTextContentType);
  res.end("INDEX");
});

router.get("/index.html", (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(httpStatusCodes.OK, htmlContentType);
  customReadFile("views/index.html", res);
});

router.get("/image.png", (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(httpStatusCodes.OK, pngContentType);
  customReadFile("public/images/image.png");
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(httpStatusCodes.OK, plainTextContentType);
  res.end("POSTED");
});

http.createServer(router.handle).listen(3000);
console.log(`The server is listening on port number: ${port}`);
```

It works just fine for loading the /index.html file, but when I try to load /image.png (stored in the correct folder, public/images/image.png) it always crashes with the error message TypeError: Cannot read property 'end' of undefined.

This happens no matter what image I use and happens also if I move the image to another folder, such as views. I have also tried writing res.write(data); res.end() instead, also to no avail. I have also tried using an async function within fs.readFile but I don't think that should be the issue here, because fs.readFile should itself execute synchronously within the function if I understand correctly.

### Edit

The code for router.js, in case that helps:

```
const httpStatus = require("http-status-codes"),
  htmlContentType = {
    "Content-Type": "text/html",
  },
  routes = {
    GET: {
      "/info": (req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(httpStatus.OK, {
          "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        });
        res.end("Welcome to the Info Page!");
      },
    },
    POST: {},
  };

exports.handle = (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (routes[req.method][req.url]) {
      routes[req.method][req.url](req, res);
    } else {
      res.writeHead(httpStatus.NOT_FOUND, htmlContentType);
      res.end("<h1>No such file exists</h1>");
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log("error: " + ex);
  }
};

exports.get = (url, action) => {
  routes["GET"][url] = action;
};

exports.post = (url, action) => {
  routes["POST"][url] = action;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the `res` object as a second argument to your `customReadFile` function to make it work. What you have:

```
router.get("/image.png", (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(httpStatusCodes.OK, pngContentType);
  customReadFile("public/images/image.png"); // <-- 2nd arg missing
});
```

What you want to have:

```
router.get("/image.png", (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(httpStatusCodes.OK, pngContentType);
  customReadFile("public/images/image.png", res); // <-- 2nd arg added
});
```